# Playing different youtube videos using Youtube Player API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I´m using the Youtube Player API for Android to play videos selecting one of these in a `listview` (videos are previously got parsing json etc etc). The problem comes when I can only play the first video of the `listview` that I select, cause the player view doesnt change when I do click in a different element of the listView. This is the important code:

```
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pariente, View view, 
                    int posicion, long id) {

                Video chosen = (Video)pariente.getItemAtPosition(posicion); 
                String urlVideo = chosen.getUrl();
                String aux = getYoutubeVideoId(urlVideo);
                URL_VIDEO = aux;

                youTubeView.initialize(KEY_DEVELOPER, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                            YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("DEPURANDO: ERROR AL VISUALIZAR", URL_VIDEO);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(!wasRestored){       
                            Log.d("YOUTUBE", "URL: " + URL_VIDEO);
                            player.cueVideo(URL_VIDEO);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

---

I understand the problem comes because the player can't be initialized twice, so the execution only enter once in `OnInitializationSucess` (I tested) and therefore only plays the first video. how to solve this problem?

Comment: I've tried making a player in listview type of application, which I failed miserably. When you play your first video in the listview, have you tried scrolling the list? In my phone it leaves a black rectangle everywhere in the listview when I'm scrolling, does same thing happens to you?

Comment: Mmmm no, I dont get the same error, after cliking ina video the listview keep working fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the last version of the YouTube API Samples

[YouTube API Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/)

I think this sample can be useful to you:

[youtube-api-samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/VideoListDemoActivity.java)

Comment: this tutorial worked to me Cristiana214, I hope it helps you too: http://androiddev101.com/episode-12-youtube-it-all-night-long/

Answer (score 6):

You just need to initialize once, and store the player in your class

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
     if(!wasRestored){       
         mPlayer = player;
     }
}
```

After that, you could play any Youtube URL on your `mPlayer` by calling the function.

```
public void playVideo(String url) {
     if( mPlayer != null ) {
          mPlayer.cueVideo(url);
     }
}
```

Comment: thnq, this helped me, I ll post my code in comment.

Comment: very helpful, searched lot to find it.

Answer (score 0):

On click, just scrollListToPosition(position)
& if the item is last item in list then you can give padding by calculating the top of item.
Alternatively use YouTubeStandalonePlayer to play video

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) mContext, YOU_TUBE_API_KEY, VideoID[getLayoutPosition()], 100, false, true);

mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very old, but solution for people coming after this post.

First initialise YoutubePlayerView and store YoutubePlayer object in class variable.

```
youTubeView.initialize(KEY_DEVELOPER, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("DEPURANDO: ERROR AL VISUALIZAR", URL_VIDEO);

                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                    youtubePlayer = player;
                }
            });
```

here "youtubePlayer" is a variable of YoutubePlayer class.

Now inside onclick listener load your video in youtubePlayer

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pariente, View view, 
                int posicion, long id) {

            Video chosen = (Video)pariente.getItemAtPosition(posicion); 
            String urlVideo = chosen.getUrl();
            String aux = getYoutubeVideoId(urlVideo);
            URL_VIDEO = aux;
            youtubePlayer.load(URL_VIDEO);
        }
```