# Displaying and playing multiple video using youtube player API

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

I stumble upon issue playing more than 1 video using youtube API.

I found this article: [Playing different youtube videos using Youtube Player API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508933/playing-different-youtube-videos-using-youtube-player-api)

**Problem:**

I cant find how it solved by keep more than 1 player on same page.

I'm trying to init 2 player with 2 different video code, but when i
tried to play 1 video, both run, then after 1 second, both stopped.

How can i fix it? Can anyone guide me?

Here's my code:

```
public class YoutubeTvFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String LOG = "Youtube TV";

    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer, YPlayer2;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv_youtube, container, false);



        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerSupportFragment).commit();

        youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                    YPlayer.cueVideo("eCdXcZeKgxU");

                    //YPlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                    //YPlayer.pause();
                    //YPlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment2 = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.add(R.id.youtube_fragment2, youTubePlayerSupportFragment2).commit();

        youTubePlayerSupportFragment2.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean c) {
                if (!c) {
                    YPlayer2 = youTubePlayer;
                    YPlayer2.cueVideo("jgnGD74BKoA");

                    //YPlayer2.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                    //YPlayer2.pause();
                    //YPlayer2.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });



        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044146/how-to-play-multiple-videos-in-youtube-player-api

Comment: i believe i already put this url also in my question, and said there is no response there that i could understand, and hope can clarify again here

Comment: Mr.Rebot its not duplicate its some other problem @Gabriel is trying to add multiple youtube players but not one displaying multiple videos.